Contribution: How to create membership with contribution?
I have tried to created a profil with field that are coming from different data group but it's telling me that I can't mix the data group ''organisation'' and ''contact''.
So I have decide to create to separate profil to integrate to my contribution but it's not showing me the profil I have created cause it's with ''contact'' field.
How can my member register ?

Hard to say for sure but ... on a Contribution page you can set it to work 'on behalf of' organisation. therefore you can set up a profile for the Org information with the org field and use the standard profile for putting in the fields you want to collect data about the person submitting the form

Welcome Caroline!  It's a bit hard to understand your setup.  Could you please edit your question to include a screenshot?  Could you also confirm that this is a public-facing contribution page and not a back-end process?
Also - the title of your question doesn't match its text.  Do you need to know how to create a contribution page that creates a membership?  Or do you need to resolve the issue of putting all the profile fields on one profile?
